# Grub install fatal error

Tags: grub2

I'm struggling to install Ubuntu on NUC 6i5syk with single drive, only fresh Ubuntu  20.10 install, no other OS's.
On install finish i get
Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed.
This is a fatal error.
UEFI/Legacy both same result

Comment: Better to use UEFI with gpt partitioning. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair intel nuc - nuc5i5MYHE w/M.2 SSD 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376245
boot into the EFI shell and manually point startup.nsh to the grubx64.cfg and run it

Comment: Thank you very much my friend for help, today i had problems booting from sd card used yesterday to run live and install, so i tried to do it from usb stick. I did install, and it went without grub error, Ubuntu is now running